# MSSQL - Can Maintenance Plan wait for Agent Job Task to be completed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I did start a **Maintenance Plan** project with **Execute SQL Server Agent Job Task** box. I added another task on success event. I realized that I was wrong. The second task is executed in parallel, because first task executing was successful (executing but not completing - important reason).

So question is - can I connect second task in that way, that the first task (agent job) is fully completed (not just fired)?

Comment: In fact a first job was a single step backup - so it was to exchange it to **database backup task** - and a case is solved - but the question is still open.

Comment: You can answer your own question- and if you've genuinely solved the problem, please do so others will benefit.  If you still have a question, please edit to reflect what is yet unanswered.

Comment: This is only a workaround. A question is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

When you start an agent job, it returns immediately with a success message.

Take a look at this post (http://agilebi.com/cs/blogs/jwelch/archive/2009/02/20/check-for-sql-agent-job-completion.aspx)